# SplashScreen logo is shown rounded, not squared with rounded corners. Why?

Tags: android, splash-screen

I've used this tutorial in Medium: https://medium.com/@radomir9720/android-splash-screen-easy-setup-for-both-11-version-and-lower-and-12-287ccb86f9c7

This is my logo drawable:

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="171dp"
    android:height="171dp"
    android:viewportWidth="171"
    android:viewportHeight="171">
  <path
      android:pathData="M55.38,28L114.62,28A27.38,27.38 0,0 1,142 55.38L142,114.62A27.38,27.38 0,0 1,114.62 142L55.38,142A27.38,27.38 0,0 1,28 114.62L28,55.38A27.38,27.38 0,0 1,55.38 28z"
      android:fillColor="#303030"/>
  <path
      android:pathData="M61.68,88.94C61.68,102.24 72.16,113.02 85.02,113.02C97.87,113.02 108.35,102.21 108.32,88.94C108.32,82.57 105.88,75.15 101.74,69.07C96.96,62.02 90.87,58.12 84.66,58.12C70.83,58.12 61.68,76.69 61.68,88.94ZM69.33,88.94C69.33,79.14 76.91,66.01 84.66,66.01C92.63,66.01 100.7,79.34 100.7,88.94C100.7,97.87 93.67,105.13 85.01,105.13C76.36,105.13 69.33,97.87 69.33,88.94Z"
      android:fillColor="#ffffff"
      android:fillType="evenOdd"/>
</vector>
```

This is how it should be seen

[image: vector drawable image]

And the layer list xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:drawable="@color/Accent_900"/>
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/b4w_logo_splash"
        android:gravity="center"
    />
</layer-list>
```

But this is how is seen in the app

[image: rounded logo]

How can I fix it? The logo is a clear square of 171dp and the image inside is 114 dp (square/1.5)

I tried to perform all the steps in the medium tutorial

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per this  [documentation](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/launch/splash-screen),  Android itself mask the image as circular, So we can't explicitly change the shape of that Icon View, but we can do some trick to set icon as Square with rounded corner. You can ware your image with `inset` attribute and adjust the size as you want.

I have tried your Image and this one works for me.

```
<inset xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:drawable="@drawable/ic_egg"
    android:insetLeft="30dp"
    android:insetRight="30dp"
    android:insetTop="30dp"
    android:insetBottom="30dp"/>
```

[image: SplashScreen Icon after adding above code]

Comment: Create a new drawable and place this code inside, change this "android:drawable="@drawable/ic_egg" drawable name to your drawable name. And call the newly created drawable in themes, where you set Icon for your splash screen. Also you can adjust "30dp" dimension that I have provided with your taste.